# Unit Testing functions to check dispatch to be called

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, redux, jestjs

store.js

```
const store = createStore(state,...) 
export default store;
```

myfunction.js

```
import store from './store'

const myFunction = async ()=>{
  store.dispatch(...some actions);
};

export default myFunction;
```

mytest.js

```
import store from './store';
import myFunction from './myfunction';

describe("myFunction", ()=>{
  it("should call dispatch" ()=>{

    await myFunction()

    // test something like below
    expect(store.dispatch).toBeCalled();

 })
})
```

Hi I would like to have a unit test on my helper function in react/redux application. I have created a sample functions above to give you some context.

As you can see, `myFunction` imports `store` and uses `store.dispatch` inside. I would like to check if `store.dispatch` has been called or not, but I am hard time achieving this. Mocking does not seem to be working because it only mocks the instance that was imported in `mytest.js` not the one in `myFunction.js`

I have tried to spy on it like

```
const spyStore = jest.spyOn(store, "dispatch");
```

and I am getting error that says dispatch is undefined.

Any clues for this kind of situation?

I would greatly appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to mock store module like this?

```
jest.mock('./store', ()=> ({
   dispatch: jest.fn(),
}));
```

Comment: Damn it works! I have been battling by using jest.doMock, but I guess it was just jest.mock. Thanks a million!